# I'm trying to specify the reply-to address in the template "return_notification_email.html"

Tags: bigcommerce

Can I edit a template or check a box or do something which allows the Return Request notification which is sent to the email specified in the Store Profile to have a reply-to address of the customer that submits the request?

This way it'll look like it's coming from the user and I can reply to it normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you use a custom form rather than the builtin forms. You can build it using javascript, a prebuilt resource, or an app from the BC app store.